# apt-rdepends php8.2 on ubuntu focal (20.04) depends on media-types

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, ubuntu-20.04

I am trying to install `php8.2` on an offline Ubuntu 20.04 (focal) system.

I found a guide on [OSTechNix](https://ostechnix.com/download-packages-dependencies-locally-ubuntu/) to download a package and its dependencies.

My first attempt at downloading `php8.2` dependencies, yielded:

```
$ apt-get download $(apt-rdepends php8.2 | grep -v "^ ")
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Can't select candidate version from package apache2-api-20120211 as it has no candidate
E: Can't select candidate version from package debconf-2.0 as it has no candidate
E: Can't select candidate version from package libaprutil1-dbd-freetds as it has no candidate
E: Can't select candidate version from package media-types as it has no candidate
E: Can't select candidate version from package time-daemon as it has no candidate
E: Can't select candidate version from package systemd-tmpfiles as it has no candidate
```

I followed instructions on the page to attempt to fix the missing candidates, by searching for them one-by-one and came up with:

```
$ apt-get download $(apt-rdepends php8.2 | grep -v "^ " | \
  sed 's/debconf-2.0/debconf/g' | \
  sed 's/apache2-api-20120211/apache2-bin/g' | \
  sed 's/time-daemon/ntp/g' | \
  sed 's/systemd-tmpfiles/systemd/g' | \
  sed 's/libaprutil1-dbd-freetds/apr-util/g')
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree
    Reading state information... Done
    E: Can't select candidate version from package media-types as it has no candidate
```

Now, media-types is a package that is originated in the next version of ubuntu (jammy and onwards).

How do I skip media-types as a candidate?

Comment: I have pointed media-types to some random package, so that the other packages can download. lemme see what the offline system yields.